# Objective C custom operator functions

Tags: objective-c, function, operators

Is it possible to have operator like functions in Obj C? Some thing like:

```
int a = b times c;

-(int)times:(int)v1 :(int)v2{
 return v1*v2;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Objective-C does not support definition or overloading of operators. One reason is that objc is a superset of C and it would be difficult to add custom operators without touching C semantics.

Also, Objective-C is about objects. It leaves the rest of the language untouched. In your example there's no obvious *receiver* for the message.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C doesn't support operators overloading, but it is still C and you can use plain old C functions like this

```c
int times(int a, int b) {
    return a * b;
}
```